# Buddhist facilities

Tags: words, meaning, religion

I am working on Japanese texts describing Buddhist temples in South-East Asia and there is quite a number of words I can't really translate in English. Here is a list with my tentative translations (I wrote a ~ next to the words whose meaning I am really unsure of):

- 結界石{けっかいせき} (~): rules tablet/barrier stones
- 布薩堂{ふさつどう}　(~): confession hall
- 講堂{こうどう}: auditorium
- サーラー さぁらぁ(~): open pavillion
- 僧坊{そうぼう}: monk cell
- 鼓楼{ころう}: drum tower
- 三蔵庫{さんぞうく}: library
- 仏教{さんぞう}教育{きょういく}学校{がっこう}: buddhist school
- 普通{ふつう}教育{きょういく}学校{がっこう}: regular school
- 火葬場{かそうば}: funeral hall
- 仏塔{ぶっとう}式納{しきのう}骨塔{こつとう}: bone keep in pagoda
- 壁式{かべしき}納骨所{のうこつば}: bone keep in wall
- 瞑想場{めいそうば}: meditation hall
- 洞窟{どうくつない}内仏{ぶつ}像祭壇{ぞうさいだん}: altar in cave
- 精霊祠{しょうりょうし}: guardian spirit house
- 碑文{ひぶん}: epitaph/scriptures

Does this look fine?

Comment: Some of these are listed in the excellent "Digital Dictionary of Buddhism" (電子佛教辭典): http://www.buddhism-dict.net/ddb/ .

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! It helped with "結界石" which is apparently translated as "rules tablet". It might be the time to visit the South-East Asian Studies department of my local university :)

Comment: For the benefit of other people who would be interested in these words, please add furigana. :)

Comment: Also, I think 火葬場 is "crematorium", not "funeral hall", but maybe the context you're coming from changes it.

Comment: Some words are awkward (e.g.,　普通教育学校), and some sound not like a single word but like a temporarily made up expression (e.g., 仏塔式納骨塔, 壁式納骨所, 洞窟内仏像祭壇).

Comment: @DaveMG I added the furigana. Indeed,火葬場 is crematorium but that's also the place where they hold the burial ceremony in South-East Asian Buddhist temples, that's why I translated it as funeral hall (mentioned as funeral hall in several references too)

Comment: @sawa Indeed, I'm digging through a spreadsheet listing all the temples in Luang Prabang, Laos. So I guess these terms were made up to translate something that was described in Lao originally.

Comment: I think you also need to check out the language of Chinese Buddhism. Many of those terms are Chinese. For instance, most Chinese cities even now have a 鼓楼 or drum tower.

Comment: @Bathrobe Could be a good idea. Do you know of any good chinese dictionaries? I'm using this one: http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/ at the moment.

Comment: My suggestion on Chinese was a little misguided. Many of those terms are, indeed, actually Chinese in origin, but that isn't going to help you find an English translation. I looked in some of my general Chinese dictionaries and they were not helpful. The problem is that the language is specialised, so specialised dictionaries are likely to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for adding the readings. I moved them into being furigana by enclosing them in squiggly brackets: { }. The advantage of this is that people can use the options settings at the bottom of the page to turn them off entirely if they don't need them.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this feature. Does the engine use Ruby for the Furigana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 結界石{けっかいせき}: rules tablet/barrier stones
- 布薩堂{ふさつどう}: confession hall (or: *Uposatha hall* [1](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanavara/uposatha.html))
- 講堂{こうどう}: auditorium (or: *lecture hall*)
- サーラー さぁらぁ: open pavilion (or: *open pavilion for resting*)
- 僧坊{そうぼう}: monk cell (or possibly: *monks' temple quarters*, but "cell" seems to be more of a set phrase)
- 鼓楼{ころう}: drum tower (or almost: *bell tower*.  Depending on the audience, perhaps, "bell tower" might help readers better understand that a "drum" here, is used like a "bell". [2](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%BC%93%E6%A5%BC))
- 三蔵庫{さんぞうく}: library (or: *library for the three branches of Buddhist sutras*)
- 仏教教育学校{さんぞうきょういくがっこう}: Buddhist school
- 普通教育学校{ふつうきょういくがっこう}: regular school (or: *common* school / almost: *secular* school)
- 火葬場{かそうば}: funeral hall (or *crematorium*.  However, here, using *funeral hall* helps to include the idea that funerals are often held at crematoriums, at least in Thailand. [3](http://www.thai-blogs.com/2011/08/05/what-to-expect-if-you-are-invited-to-a-thai-funeral/))
- 仏塔式納骨塔{ぶっとうしきのうこつとう}: bone keep in pagoda (or: *pagoda columbarium* [4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbarium))
- 壁式納骨所{かべしきのうこつば}: bone keep in wall (or: *columbarium wall*)
- 瞑想場{めいそうば}: meditation hall (Note: I've seen this written as めいそうじょう as well; perhaps because it's a place where people can **practice** meditation?)
- 洞窟内仏像祭壇{どうくつないぶつぞうさいだん}: altar in cave (or: *Buddhist cave shrine*)
- 精霊祠{しょうりょうし}: guardian spirit house (or just: *spirit house/shrine* because the spirits are not always guardians. [5](http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E4%BF%A1%E4%BB%B0#.E5.88.86.E9.A1.9E), [6](http://www.chiangmai-chiangrai.com/spirit_house.html))
- 碑文{ひぶん}: epitaph/scriptures (seems more like *epitaph*, here, unless a sutra is found on an epitaph, perhaps.)

Hope this helps!

*References:*

1. http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanavara/uposatha.html (found in Glossary under Uposatha part 3)
2. http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%BC%93%E6%A5%BC
3. http://www.thai-blogs.com/2011/08/05/what-to-expect-if-you-are-invited-to-a-thai-funeral/ (near middle of page)
4. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbarium
5. http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E4%BF%A1%E4%BB%B0#.E5.88.86.E9.A1.9E
6. http://www.chiangmai-chiangrai.com/spirit_house.html

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I really appreciate that you took the trouble to get the sources.

Comment: This is a great piece of detective work and obviously took a lot of time. On 'monk's cell', I think this is probably the usual naming (plenty of Google hits), although admittedly as languages change old usages do become unfamiliar and prone to misinterpretation.

Comment: @Bathrobe Thanks; and, good point about the "cell" part, too... I edited that part to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @JulienBourdon Glad I could help a little!

Comment: Also, I think that 鼓楼 is actually drum tower. The bell tower is known as 鐘楼.

Comment: @Bathrobe You're right, it is drum tower; I just left "bell tower" in there as a possible alternative translation to help readers better picture what type of tower this is referring to.  The drum tower is (at least partly,) used to tell time.  (For which bell towers, at least partly, are also used.)  I guess it depends on the audience these translations are facing... for which translation one would want to use.

Comment: @Bathrobe Regardless, I've updated the post with your suggestion in mind.